# select a viewcontroller programatically at didiSelectRowAtIndexpath in ios

Tags: ios, uitableview, segue, swrevealviewcontroller

I have a tableview with dynamic prototypes content. I want to call for a specific ViewController programatically when a dynamic cell tap. I used `SWRevealViewController` calls for my project.

When I tap on cell one with `@"l1"` identifier I want to load main view controller with `sw_front` , used in `SWRevealViewController`. I cannot use controll+drag becaue in her I have use `tabviewcontrller`. When I do that it disappear the tab bar.

```
#import "ListViewController.h"

@interface ListViewController ()

@end

@implementation ListViewController
{
    NSArray *menuItems;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    menuItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"l1",@"l2",@"l3",@"l6",@"l4",@"l5",@"l7", nil];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [menuItems count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellIdentifier = [menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ([cell.reuseIdentifier isEqualToString:@""]) {

        UIViewController *mainviewcontroller = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController *navi = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainviewcontroller];
        [self.navigationController presentViewController:navi animated:YES completion:nil];


    }
}
```

Comment: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1 didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath use this method for getting which cell is tapped

Comment: Do you want to **change with SWRevealViewController** the currently visible ViewController with another ViewController or do you want to make a **push segue**?

Comment: r u used storyboard or xib

Comment: i use storyboard @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: yes I want to change with swrevealviewcontroller with sw_front @Islam Q

Comment: sorry for the delay guys , I'm new to stackoverflow. please help me

Comment: @anuk, have you give identifier to individual UIViewControllers where you want to push?

Comment: do you meant storyboard ID @None

Comment: @anuk, yes...set storyboard ID to each view controllers like viewController1, viewController2 etc..

Answer (score 0):

If you already set `storyboard ID` then you can push programmatically using following code.

Here **viewController1**, **viewController2** etc are storyboard Id of individual `UIViewController`.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIViewController *pushViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"viewController%ld",indexPath.row]];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:pushViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: thanx to all, I will check it out and send you feedbacks. thanx